# Appium Test Result - Jenkins & Slack Notification

Tags: maven, jenkins, automation, appium, slack

I am running a maven project in Jenkins for Appium Automation Suite and Have configured slack notification which triggers result post build completion. I want to get information like how many tests were executed, Passed and Failed data in that slack notification. However now I can only configure test report path which gets generated in workspace post build completion. Any idea how can I achieve that?

Comment: Which reports integration have you done on your framework? You can write a slack api to post the message upon reading your reports pass/ fail count and then the same can be published on your slack channel.

Comment: I am using extent report, I will try to write the APIs if you have any resource, please let me know, that would help.